# True handwriting of Ri hiragana

Tags: hiragana, handwriting

I learned hiragana in [memrise.com](http://memrise.com) which `Ri` (`り`) has (like in `ありがとう`) a continuous form .

[image: Ri Continuous]

But in most of the devices `Ri` has a discreet shape like below:

[image: Ri Discreet]

So I am confused which one is true for handwriting? Are their usage is different?

Thanks for  any help.

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38904/1628

Comment: Both are correct. I prefer two-stroke form to the other.